# Making snakemake use as input 2 outputs of a rule with different names

Tags: snakemake

Making snakemake use as input 2 outputs of a rule with different names

I am making a snakemake pipeline in which I use strelka to compare a tumor and a normal sample. In this case I want to compare the first element of  `GERMLINE = ("PT1", "S6", "S1”)` to the first one of tumor `TUMOR = ("T5", "T7", "T20")`

- PT1 vs. T5
- S6 vs. T7
- S1 vs. T20

The pipeline works well for the initial rules: folders, strelkaconfig and strelkarun. The issue is on the postprocessing of the output of strelka as I want to do the same for both outputs:

- somatic.snvs.vcf
- somatic.indels.vcf

However, I don't know how to make snakemake understand that it should do the same for both without repeating the rule. I have tried to do the following:

```python
GERMLINE = ("PT1", "S6", "S1")
TUMOR = ("T5", "T7", "T20")
ANALYSIS = "OUTPUT_PATH"
TYPEVAR = ["snvs","indels"]
INDGATK = "ref"

rule all:
    input:
        [ANALYSIS +"/{}_vs_{}/Stelka/results/variants/somatic.snvs.vcf".format(sample_g, sample_t)
         for (sample_g, sample_t) in zip(GERMLINE, TUMOR)],
        [ANALYSIS +"/{}_vs_{}/Stelka/runWorkflow.py".format(sample_g, sample_t)
         for (sample_g, sample_t) in zip(GERMLINE, TUMOR)],
        [ANALYSIS +"/{}_vs_{}/Stelka/results/variants/somatic.{}_Filtered".format(sample_g, sample_t,typevar)
         for (sample_g, sample_t,typevar)
         in zip(GERMLINE*len(TUMOR), TUMOR*len(TUMOR),sorted(TYPEVAR*len(TUMOR)))]


# Make folders
rule folders:
    input:
        g = "{samples_g}.bam",
        t = "{samples_t}.bam"
    output: 
        gen = "/{samples_g}_vs_{samples_t}",
        strelka = "/{samples_g}_vs_{samples_t}/Stelka/"
    run: 
        '''mkdir {output.gen}
        mkdir {output.strelka}'''

# Strelka configuration
rule strelkaconfig:
    input:
        g = "{samples_g}.bam",
        t = "{samples_t}.bam",
        out_dir = ANALYSIS + "/{samples_g}_vs_{samples_t}/Stelka/"
    output:
        wfs = ANALYSIS + "/{samples_g}_vs_{samples_t}/Stelka/runWorkflow.py"
    params:
        ref = INDGATK
    shell:
        "python configureStrelkaSomaticWorkflow.py --normalBam {input.g} --tumorBam {input.t} --referenceFasta {params.ref} --runDir {input.out_dir} "

# Strelka run
rule strelkarun:
    input:
        wfs = ANALYSIS + "/{samples_g}_vs_{samples_t}/Stelka/runWorkflow.py"
    output:
        outsnvs = ANALYSIS + "/{samples_g}_vs_{samples_t}/Stelka/results/variants/somatic.snvs.vcf",
        outindels = ANALYSIS + "/{samples_g}_vs_{samples_t}/Stelka/results/variants/somatic.indels.vcf"
    shell:
        "python {input.wfs}"

# POSTPROCESSING
rule vcfp:
    input: ANALYSIS + "/{samples_g}_vs_{samples_t}/Stelka/results/variants/somatic.{typevar}.vcf"
    output: ANALYSIS + "/{samples_g}_vs_{samples_t}/Stelka/results/variants/somatic.{typevar}_Filtered.vcf"
    shell:
        "java -jar StrelkaVCFParser -v {input} "
```

But when I dry run I get this error:

```
MissingInputException in line 15 of pipe:
Missing input files for rule folders:
T7/Stelka/results/variants/somatic.indels_Filtered.bam
```

Comment: You don't need to have a rule to create folders if other rules have as output files in those folders. Snakemake will then automatically create those folders. It may even cause problems if the rule creating the files have as input the folders: The folders will be considered modified after the output files will be written. So next time you run the pipeline, snakemake will see that the input has been modified and will run the rule again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the pipeline is inferring the wildcards to be something else than you expect.

You could try using [wildcard constraints](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#wildcards), as follows:

```python
wildcard_constraints:
    samples_g = "|".join(GERMLINE)
    samples_t = "|".join(TUMOR)
```

This probably doesn't solve your issue, but the third input of your `all` rule doesn't look very clean to me. You can achieve the same using two successive `expand`, with the first one using `zip`, as follows:

```python
expand(expand(
    ANALYSIS + "/{sample_g}_vs_{sample_t}/Stelka/results/variants/somatic.{{typevar}}_Filtered",
    zip, sample_g=GERMLINE, sample_t=TUMOR), typevar=TYPEVAR)
```

Note the double curly braces around `typevar`, so that it doesn't get expanded by the first expand.

You can test this in a python3 interpreter after doing `from snakemake.io import expand`.

I personally find if easier to understand.